# Is the angel of Genesis 16:7 "the" angel of the LORD?

Tags: genesis, hebrews, angels, christology

In the first appearance of the term "angel of the LORD" in the scriptures there is no definite article:

> Gen 16:7  And *the* angel of the LORD found her by a fountain of water
>   in the wilderness, by the fountain in the way to Shur.

In fact it appears that none of the references to the Angel of the LORD have the definite article.

Is there any reason to think that this is a/the special angel aka "THE Angel of the LORD"? Or is this just an everyday angel? AN angel of the LORD.

In fact, aren't all the appearances of "THE Angel of the LORD" just appearances of regular old angels?

> Heb 1:14  Are they not **all** ministering spirits, sent forth to
>   minister for them who shall be heirs of salvation?

Comment: Actually in hebrew it's מלאך יהוה - God's angel. There is no THE (ה) here.

Comment: The Hebrew definite article doesn't quite correspond 1:1 with ours. Cf. Zech 12:8.

Comment: @SolaGratia  How not? I mean, how not that is relevant here?

Comment: Well, I mean "God's angel" and "an angel of God" and "the angel of the Lord" are different in nuance, but all are equally valid translations of מלאך יהוה. Seeing specialness to the angel, or seeing him as a generic angel, is up to context, pretty much.

Comment: @SolaGratia  I'm convinced that the angel(s) of the YHVH that people take as "the second person of the Trinity" are worshiping angels. The angels are not YHVH, they are messengers. They might turn into flames of fire or wind and speak for YHVH in the first person or third, no problem. But they are not God. They are not even sons.

Comment: How, if they have identified Him as *God*, could they be worshiping *angels*. In this case מלאך would refer to role (cf. Mal 3:1) rather than a nature as a creature commonly called angel... that this specific מלאך is Christ is up for grabs or rejection by anyone. It doesn't say either way.

Comment: If one worships the angel instead of the LORD whom he represents then they are committing idolatry!

Comment: If the מלאך is a creature, then obviously that's idolatry. If He is as you say the Second Person of the Trinity (i.e. He is God), then obviously it's no idolatry, since God is not an idol.

Comment: @SolaGratia I think Ruminator was trying to say that, in his opinion, *none* of the occurrences of מלאך יהוה refer to the Second Person of the Blessed Trinity.

Comment: I'm not sure he is. I already know he doesn't believe in the Trinity. But he is saying that if this angel actually referred to the Second Person of the Holy Trinity (read: if it referred to God) it would still be 'idolatry' because He is 'an angel.' As I pointed out, that ignores the distinction between that mode of creature we call Angels, and a messenger in general, and that since the hypothetical person has called Him God, this is exclusive of the former understanding of מלאך.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very elementary question about Hebrew grammar. מלאך יהוה means “the angel of Yahweh”. The first word does not, and cannot, take the definite article “the” (ה) because it is defined by the following possessive noun. If you wanted to say “an angel of Yahweh” you would have to say the equivalent of “an angel from the angels of Yahweh”. That is how Semitic languages work.

Comment: So are you saying that it is indefinite? IE: "an" and not "the"?

Comment: I am saying the exact opposite. @Ruminator

Comment: That it is definite? IE: "the" and not "an"? Okay, I see, sorry, thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a primary source that says that in order be indefinite the syntax requires "an angel of the angels of the LORD"? Thanks.